# Недоступен порт после подключение VPN

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn

Есть сервер, на котором установлена kali linux как основная ОС (kali). К этому серверу я подключаюсь через переадресацию портов на маршутизаторе (192.168.1.1 - маршутизатор). Все работает до момента активации VPN на kali, после этого сервер остается недоступен через переадресацию портов, но также остается доступен из локальной сети. Что нужно сделать чтобы при включение впна работало подключение через переадресацию портов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. программы route, ifconfig, arp — окаменелости прошлого века, сейчас работают некорректно. используйте программу ip. 2. чем ниже метрика маршрута, тем выше его прироритет. присваивайте нужные вам метрики нужным вам маршрутам. 3. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: что вам непонятно во втором пункте? «чем ниже метрика маршрута, тем выше его прироритет. присваивайте нужные вам метрики нужным вам маршрутам»

Comment: Не понятно ничего.

Comment: Если вас не затруднит вы могли бы написать полноценный ответ с примерами и пояснением какая команда что делает, если вы считаете что тут все гении и профи то это не так.

Comment: начать можно со [статьи в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Таблица_маршрутизации)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin `ifconfig` до сих пор на маке. `ip` надо ставить отдельно через брю. Стало быть еще не окаменелости.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, речь не о маке, а о программе linux. для неё (начиная с версии 2.1 (или 2.0, не помню уже) перечисленные программы — действительно некорректно работающие окаменелости прошлого века. // почитайте, пожалуйста: https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=129712

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin На маке также называется, я думаю тоже самое.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, я не знаю об особенностях реализации сетевого стека в ядре apple/macos. в программе же linux он был переписан на рубеже веков. почитайте, пожалуйста, https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=129712

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin thx!Не знал. ok

Comment: роутер какой модели?

Comment: @eri EdgeRouter X SFP

Comment: @Андрей родная ваята или опенврт?

Answer (score 1):

#### предуведомление:

Так как в вопросе приведено катастрофически мало информации, ответ пришлось создавать универсальным, содержащим лишь возможные направления в ущерб большей конкретике.

---

Судя по всему, пакеты, приходящие к серверу от вашего компьютера через маршрутизатор, содержат в поле «адрес отправителя» не адрес маршрутизатора (`192.168.1.1`), а тот адрес, под которым вас «знает» маршрутизатор.

Когда программа на сервере (вероятно, *sshd*) отправляет ответный пакет, и указывает получателем этот адрес, то в соответствии с приведённой таблицей маршрутизации сервер отправит его не маршрутизатору через интерфейс `eth0`, с которого пришёл ваш пакет, а внутрь туннеля через интерфейс `tun0`. где этот ответный пакет будет благополучно отброшен.

Почему будет выбран умолчальный маршрут (вообще-то «один из двух», так как их у вас получается два)? потому что «адрес отправителя» отсутствует в таблице маршрутизации.

Почему будет выбран умолчальный маршрут через `tun0`, а не через `eth0`? потому что у этого маршрута **ниже** метрика (`50` в противовес `100`).

Возможные пути решения (в порядке предпочтительности и реалистичности):

1. сконфигурировать маршрутизатор так, чтобы он осуществлял подмену адреса отправителя пакета при передаче между своими интерфейсами (т.н. «[маскарадинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)»)
2. добавить в таблицу маршрутизации вашего сервера (где создаётся туннель) маршрут к «адресу отправителя» через интерфейс `eth0`
3. <s>сконфигурировать программу, создающую туннель (вероятно, это [*openvpn*](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=8759)) так, чтобы создаваемые маршруты имели более высокую метрику (больше `100`)</s>. увы, не работает.
4. если для создания туннеля используется в качестве дополнительного посредника какой-нибудь «менеджер сетевых подключений» ([*network-manager*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349356/110559) и т.п.), сконфигурировать метрику для маршрутов туннеля его средствами
5. уменьшить значение метрики для маршрутов интерфейса `eth0` (меньше `50`)
6. сконфигурировать тот сервер, к которому подключается ваш сервер для поднятия туннеля, чтобы тот сервер отдавал клиентам (т.е. вашему серверу) указания о создании маршрутов с нужной вам метрикой (больше `100`)

Comment: 1. Подмену адреса отправителя на какой адрес ?  Нужно будет для каждого адреса с которого будет происходить подключение добавлять новое правило ?                                                                                   2. В какую таблицу, какого сервера ?

Comment: 3. Как это сделать ? В приведенной вами статье рекомендуется добавить в конфиг openvpn строчку "route-metric 101", но как и у автора стати так и у меня данная опция не работает и метрика не изменяется.

Comment: 1.1. на адрес интерфейса, с которого пакет покидает маршрутизатор. 1.2. нет. почитайте, пожалуйста, про «маскарадинг». 2. в таблицу маршрутизации вашего сервера (про который у вас написано в вопросе). 3. если не работает — значит вычёркивам.

Comment: 2. Пробую задать маршрутизацию вот таким образом 
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.200.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE#
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT#
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT#
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT#
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT#                                               Но к сожалению не работает. Как бы я не писал перевод строки, все равно в 1 строчку. Для удобства в конце каждой строки я добавил #

Comment: 2. программа iptables и подсистема netfilter программы linux никакого отношения к маршрутизации не имеют. добавляются/удаляются/просматриваются маршруты программой *ip* с параметром `route` (можно сократить до `r`. например, добавить маршрут к хосту через указанный интерфейс: `ip r a ip-адрес dev интерфейс`. // если у вас возникнут новые вопросы, задайте их, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica если хотите поправить регистр букв — нет проблем. но не вносите, пожалуйста, изменений в суть ответа.

Comment: ok.............

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, ещё раз: пожалуйста, не вносите изменений в суть ответа.

Comment: сейчас-то что??

Comment: И че из-за `:`?